# How to rename the checkbox text which is dynamically created in android

Tags: android, random, checkbox, android-checkbox

In my code, If we need particular number of checkbox or radio button, by giving the count value in EditText, we can get the particular number of checkbox. But It is displaying the checkbox with random alphabets from a to z. But, I need it to change/rename specifically based on my need. Your help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance. Here is my code.

XML Layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="05dp"
            android:hint="Enter Text" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="05dp"
            android:text="Edit Text" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
            android:text="Check Box" />

    <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="98dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button4"
            android:text="Radio Button" />


    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:hint="Enter no" />


    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/button5"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

    <RadioGroup
            android:id="@+id/radiogroup"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Main Activity

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.*;
import android.widget.LinearLayout.*;

import java.util.Random;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private LinearLayout mLayout;
    private EditText mEditText;
    private Button mButton;
    Button abutton;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        mLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.button1);
        mButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        mButton.setOnClickListener(onClick());
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("New text");


        final EditText button2=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.button3);

        findViewById(R.id.button5).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int number=Integer.parseInt(button2.getText().toString());
                addRadioButtons(number);
            }
        });

        findViewById(R.id.button4).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                int number=Integer.parseInt(button2.getText().toString());
                addCheckBox(number);
            }
        });
    }
    public void addRadioButtons(int number) {

        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                RadioButton rdbtn = new RadioButton(this);
                rdbtn.setId((row * 2) + i);
                rdbtn.setText("Radio " + rdbtn.getId());
                ll.addView(rdbtn);
            }
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
        }

    }

    public void addCheckBox(int number) {

        //Edited Here
        String[] names = {"Sanket", "Kumar", "Rahul"};

        for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
            LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
            ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

            for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
                ch.setId((row * 2) + i);

                //ch.setText(randomString(3));

                ch.setText(names[i]);
                ll.addView(ch);
            }
            ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
        }


    }
    private String randomString(int len) {
        char[] chars = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(len);
        Random random = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            char c = chars[random.nextInt(chars.length)];
            sb.append(c);
        }
        String output = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(output);
        return sb.toString();
    }
    private OnClickListener onClick() {
        return new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mLayout.addView(createNewTextView(mEditText.getText().toString()));
            }
        };
    }

    private TextView createNewTextView(String text) {
        final LayoutParams lparams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        final TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setLayoutParams(lparams);
        textView.setText("" + text);
        return textView;
    }


}
```

Comment: not clear enough...please explain it more.

Comment: Please see this screenshot..I don't need the random alphabets like DJP, ZRP, POU...I need to put it manually like kalyan, simple, etc.. screenshot is here mediafire.com/view/1fzofyyyk8gf27z/issue.PNG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an String Array like

```
String[] names = {"Sanket", "Kumar", ......};
```

then in the code

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
                ch.setId((row * 2) + i);

                // Replace the line with
                //ch.setText(randomString(3)); 

                // with this line
                ch.setText(names[i]);  

                ll.addView(ch);
            }
```

Comment: Edited.. please review it... @user1504792

Comment: @user1504792: It shows error as array initializer is not allowed here

Comment: Error:(28,17) java: illegal start of expression  ..Then Array initializer is not allowed here...error is in this line... names = {"Sanket", "Kumar"};      //Edited

Comment: got it..Thanks Droid. Is there any way to manually enter the names of checkbox instead of giving the names in the array?

Comment: You can Ask user to provide names.. and store those names in an arraylist...please vote up for my answer or accept the answer.. so that it can help others

Comment: upvoted +1 and tick as answer..How to do that in array list? I am new to android...can you please help me?

Comment: ya..but it should visible as a text of checkbox like Droid, Kumar etc..Is it possible?

Comment: yes dear it is possible..just make the edittext that accept the String in CSV format.. And Split the String in Edittext to get into an array :)

Comment: Oh. But I don't know how to do that :( If you have time, please provide me the code Droid.

Answer (score 0):

In your addCheckBox() method, you have set the text of checkbox to randomstring **(ch.setText(randomString(3)))**. Just change this line as your choice just like this **ch.setText("Checkbox" + i)**.

Comment: This I did already. My question is I have to set the checkbox name like sanket, kumar, etc...

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
                CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
                ch.setId((row * 2) + i);
                ch.setText(randomString(3)); // Change Here
                ll.addView(ch);
            }
```

change the text of checkBox in ch.setText that you want to be

Comment: This I know, the problem is with that line only..I need help to change that line to fix my issue..can you get my question?

Answer (score 0):

Ok.. I really don't understand... When you create the checkbox you set its text to  ch.setText(randomString(3)); Why would you do that if you want specific text ?

Random != Specific.

Just write something like this:

```
ch.setText("Your desired text");
```

Or you could create an

```
String[] checkBoxFruits= {"apple","mango","kiwi"};
```

and then set the text something like:

```
for ( int i=0; i<numberOfCheckBoxes; i++ )
{
 CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
 ch.setId((row * 2) + i);
 ch.setText(checkBoxFruits[i]);
 ll.addView(ch);
}
```

Comment: I know random!=specific..For understanding purpose, I code like that... I know the changes to be made in that line..but need correct answer

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addCheckBox(int number) {

    String[] names = {"Sanket", "Kumar", "Eagle"};
    for (int row = 0; row < 1; row++) {
        LinearLayout ll = new LinearLayout(this);
        ll.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);

        for (int i = 1; i <= number; i++) {
            CheckBox ch = new CheckBox(this);
            ch.setId((row * 2) + i);
            if(i != names.length)
               ch.setText(names[i-1]);
            else
               ch.setText("New name");
            ll.addView(ch);
        }
        ((ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.radiogroup)).addView(ll);
    }


}
```

Use above code.. And check it...

Comment: Good one. If I need 3 names, what shall I do? If I give it as 3, it is showing Sanket, Kumar, New Name...I want it to be Sanket, Kumar, Eagle.  Added +1 to your answer

Answer (score 0):

I think you should try using RadioGroup and create an array of strings with which can easily use .setText method to run a loop throgh all the Radio Buttons.

Comment: Elaborate with examples.

Comment: Please add a documentation link to the `setText` method and try to add an example of using it